# Editing Bootstrap default styles

Tags: css, sass, navbar

I want to modify the color and the border in a Bootstrap nav bar but when I write this on my SCSS nothing happens:

```
.nav-link.active {
    color: #495057;
    background-color: chartreuse;
    border-color: black;
}
```

When I inspect the element in Chrome my code is dismissed, It only takes into account the Bootstrap default style.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itsEO.png)

Any help will be welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: You either need to load your CSS after Bootstrap or make your rule more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) in order to override it

Answer (score 1):

For a CSS rule to be overriden, you have a lot of options. The cleanest would be to be more specific (by at least one rule) than the one you want to override.

If I follow your example:

```
.nav-tabs li.nav-link.active {
    color: #495057;
    background-color: chartreuse;
    border-color: black;
}
```

You'll find more informations here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Thanks man, but it doesn't work... I copied it and pasted it in my _nav.scss and nothing happens. Thanks anyway

Comment: I don't know if your element is a `<li>`, maybe it's a `a`. You can try also to put a `.container` before. You need to be more accurate, in any way possible.
If nothing works, you can put `!important` at the end of your rule.